# hide files and folder on subdomain

Tags: image, .htaccess, subdomain

I use a subdomain to host my website pictures with a structure something like this :

- Logo

img123456

img123457

...

- Header
- ...

I would like, if it's possible, hide all file and folder if I visit the url:
For example, http://ged.website.com/
should display any folders or files inside. Howewer, if I visit the complete url to img, we can see the picture. Htaccess or any other idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess`, use:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Thank you, could you give more informations or details, maybe if you have any example to understand how to use it?

Comment: Yes, you can read the doc: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/htaccess.html